# Post to a site using Java, navigating past the 'i agree' redirect

Tags: java, url, post

I am trying to visit a site, and get the request to be processed to follow the redirect.
i visit the i agree site, but it doesnt seem to continue past that, and keeps redirecting me

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("results");
    //String targetConfirmation18 = "";

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;

    try { 
        url = new URL("");
        //url = new URL(targetConfirmation);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        osw.write("");
        osw.flush();

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to fake your headers.  Simple as that.  If you want, for example, to spider the web using a Java-written spider, you better pass fake user-agents, pretending you're a very common navigator, like Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The site sets cookies after you do post on 18+ url. You must remember them and submit with next requests. You can easily figure it out with FireBug.

As a result, you will need to use more advanced HTTP client than simple URL. For example, [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) that allows cookie manipulation.

This section in [HTTP Client Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d4e676) specifically covers cookies.

Comment: ^ i was googling around for ages and it seemed i might need to use httpclient. Could you explain how to use httpclient in this instance? or just point me in the right direction for some examples etc.
you're answer was really appreciated

Comment: You may want to read through their tutorial. I updated the answer with a reference to specific section on cookies. It's interesting project technically, but I agree with @Stephen that it may be a violation of their terms of service. And you will effectively bypass their 18+ check, which is probably required by AU law.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are violating the [Tabcorp Terms of Service](http://www.tabcorp.com.au/terms-of-use.aspx).  They say:

> You may, using an industry-standard web browser, download and view the Content for your personal, non-commercial use only.

and

> All rights not expressly granted herein are reserved.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your problem here is the HTTP session.

When you surf to the site using browser the server creates HTTP session and sends its ID as one of the cookies. Then browser sends the cookies back on each request, so server can recognize that this is the existing session.

I think that server always redirects you to 18+ page when session is unknown.

So, why the session is unknown in your case? It is because all your requests are independent. You should do as a browser. Do not start from posting to 18+ confirmation page. Start from HTTP get that will redirect you to this page. Take cookies from response header Set-Cookie and send the cookies back using request header "Cookie".

You can also use higher level tools like Jakarta HTTP client that does this work for you automatically, but it is a good exercise to implement it yourself. I tried this technique several times and saw that it works also with standard HttpUrlConnection.

BTW, I hope that this is not your case but sometimes you have to mimic the User-Agent: present yourself as one of the known browsers. Otherwise some sites redirect you to page that says that your browser is unsupported.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I figured out my problem.
I was using a HttpPost to try and get the responses.. which kept redirecting to the 18+ page.
I changed it to a HttpGet, and it works fine! Now to extract the cookie and continue my session!

I forgot to mention, i managed to do it with the jakarta httpclient that you suggested